# How to pass a form handle to a DLL for use in Windows API?

Tags: delphi, winapi, dll, delphi-7, hwnd

First of all, I'm not too comfortable with DLL's. I've done them before, but know very little and always have problems.

This DLL I'm building requires passing a windows form handle (HWND) into the DLL function, and the DLL shall call a Windows API function using that handle. I keep getting an access violation when trying to call any function (starting from `Win7InitTaskbar`) - as if it failed to even call the function. That made me conclude that it must be the `HWND` parameter making it crash... I think...

```
library Win7;

uses
  //Do I need ShareMem?
  //ShareMem,      //<---
  Windows,
  Forms,
  JDWin7,
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}

function Win7InitTaskbar(const FormHandle: HWND): Bool; stdcall;
begin
  Result:= InitializeTaskbarAPI(FormHandle);
end;

function Win7InitForm(const FormHandle: HWND): Bool; stdcall;
begin

end;

function Win7SetTaskbarState(const AState: Cardinal): Bool; stdcall;
begin
  Result:= SetTaskbarProgressState(AState);
end;

function Win7SetTaskbarValue(const ACurrent: UInt64; const AMax: UInt64): Bool; stdcall;
begin                                        //is UInt64 Safe for DLL?
  Result:= SetTaskbarProgressValue(ACurrent, AMax);
end;

exports
  Win7InitTaskbar,
  Win7InitForm,
  Win7SetTaskbarState,
  Win7SetTaskbarValue;

begin
end.
```

Implementation of DLL functions:

```
function Win7InitTaskbar(const FormHandle: HWND): Bool;
  external W7DLL;
function Win7SetTaskbarState(const AState: Cardinal): Bool;
  external W7DLL;
function Win7SetTaskbarValue(const ACurrent: UInt64; const AMax: UInt64): Bool;
  external W7DLL;
```

I had this problem whether I used `ShareMem` or not (Which, I also do not want to use). Is it safe to publish the function with a `HWND` parameter? I tried LongWord as well, still no luck. The internal function `InitializeTaskbarAPI` does in fact work perfectly outside of the DLL, if i were to use it directly inside the app. But in this case, I want to put these in a shared DLL.

Also, is it safe to pass `UInt64` into a DLL? One of the functions was already published with this parameter type when I got the source.

Comment: Please try and remember that any time you type the words "error", "exception", or "access violation" in your question, the very next thing you should add is the **exact** error message you received (or a precise description of the error), including any error code or memory addresses. Saying "I keep getting an access violation" without any more information is pretty much meaningless. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry, the addresses never make any sense to me so I always ignore them, I can't read computer language :P But problem solved anyway.

Comment: Just because they don't make sense to you doesn't mean they're meaningless to everyone. If they didn't mean anything, they wouldn't be in the error. And because your problem is solved now doesn't mean you shouldn't include the information in **future** posts (or edit this one to add the information for others' benefit in the future).

Comment: Honestly it was a combination of many different error messages in a row, starting with an access violation, and also "EExternalException" - I get your point but I'd rather not re-break my project just to be able to post exact details.

Comment: And any idea on the `UInt64` type? I've never heard of this before, it was part of some source code I got for putting a progress indicator in the taskbar icon for Windows7. I don't presume I need it, standard progress bars use just a standard `Integer` type, I just want to know what's the difference, why would someone have used `UInt64` in the first place?

Comment: `UInt64` is an unsigned 64-bit integer (unsigned meaning no negative values and roughly double the positive range). I don't remember if D7 had `UInt64` available; if your code compiles using it, and the DLL also uses it, it should be fine to pass back and forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here appears to me to be unrelated to using Sharemem or passing `Form.Handle` to an `HWND` parameter.

It is simply a [calling convention](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions) mismatch. You export as `stdcall` but then import as `register`. Whenever you do that, runtime errors are sure to follow.

You need to do it like this:

```
function Win7InitTaskbar(const FormHandle: HWND): Bool; 
  stdcall; external W7DLL;
function Win7SetTaskbarState(const AState: Cardinal): Bool;
  stdcall; external W7DLL;
function Win7SetTaskbarValue(const ACurrent: UInt64; const AMax: UInt64): Bool;
  stdcall; external W7DLL;
```

---

And for what it is worth, you don't need Sharemem here. You only need that when you allocate memory in one module but free it in a different one. And passing `Form.Handle` to an `HWND` parameter in a DLL is not a problem. You do this all then time when you call Windows API functions.

Comment: Nice catch - quicker than I got there by 40 seconds. :) @Jerry, in the D7 help file search for `calling conventions` for an explanation of the differences.

Comment: Ah Ha! Gotta slap myself for forgetting that little piece, thanks for the catch...